# ajax call not being made sequentilally,why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made an ajax call in one of my blocks but my problem is every time this block is being executed,the ajax call is not being made sequentially,instead everytime the bold line gets executed after the italic line,but it should have first called the ajax going sequentially.

I want to know why such behaviour,not to mention that i am a beginner here.

Thanks  in advance!

```
if(pkgIdStr == 519 && !pkgFetched){
    var subscribableUnitEl =  document.getElementById('subscribableUnit');  
    var pkColEl = document.getElementById("pkCol");
    pkColEl.style.width = "50%";
    var suColEl = document.getElementById("suCol");
    suColEl.style.width = "50%";
    var pkDivEl = document.getElementById("pkDiv");
    pkDivEl.style.paddingLeft = "30%";
    subscribableUnitEl.style.display = "block";
    subscribableUnitEl.setAttribute("required","true");

     *var su_list = "";*
     $.ajax({
            url : '/user/ajax/getAvailableSUsforGenericKey.htm',
            data : 'scratchCardNumber ='+value,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function(data) {

                var json=JSON.parse(data);
                var jsonlist = json.allSU;
                var su_array = [];
                for(var i=0; i < jsonlist.length; i++){
                    var x=jsonlist[0].split(',')[1].split(': ')[1];
                    su_array.push(x);
                }
                su_list =su_array.toString();

                    },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#actionMessage').html("<p style='color: red'>cannot load the email - contact tech team please!</p>");}


            });

    **var availableSUStr =su_list ;**// registerInterface.getAvailableSUInSdcard();
                            //su to be fetched here..
    var availableSUnits = availableSUStr.split(",");
    var suOptions = subscribableUnitEl.options;
    suOptions.length = 0;
    suOptions[0] = new Option("Please Select One",-1);
    for(var j=1;j<=availableSUnits.length;++j) {
        var tokenArr = availableSUnits[j-1].split(":");
        if(tokenArr.length != 2)
            continue;
        suOptions[j] = new Option(tokenArr[1],tokenArr[0]);
    }
    pkgFetched = true;
    suOptions[0].selected=true;
    showAlert("Product key entered requires a package to be selected");
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: The ajax call is asyncronous and non-blocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ajax call is asynchronous, i.e. it is called without waiting for a result. So everything you want done (sequentially) after the call has returned, you need to put in the success function.

However, like Sparky mentioned, it is also possible to wait for the Ajax call to complete by disabling the asynchronous behaviour. In your case the Ajax call will then be:

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/user/ajax/getAvailableSUsforGenericKey.htm',
        data : 'scratchCardNumber ='+value,
        type : 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function(data) {

            var json=JSON.parse(data);
            var jsonlist = json.allSU;
            var su_array = [];
            for(var i=0; i < jsonlist.length; i++){
                var x=jsonlist[0].split(',')[1].split(': ')[1];
                su_array.push(x);
            }
            su_list =su_array.toString();

                },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#actionMessage').html("<p style='color: red'>cannot load the email - contact tech team please!</p>");}


        });
```

The code following this Ajax call will then be executed AFTER your success function has finished. I personally would not recommend this, since the browser will hang until the Ajax request completes.

Comment: Let's not forget about setting `async` option to `false`

Comment: True, it is possible to disable this asynchronous behaviour, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Woah...that just worked like a charm!  Thanks guys.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are asynchronous. What that means is that they are not called in sequence. What is happening here is that the request that you call first is finishing before the other one. Take a look at the call back pattern to try and understand it. You can then learn about promises which provide a cleaner API for doing asynchronous operations and then finally move on the async await which is part of the new ecmascript spec which uses Promises internally.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the AJAX call is executing after the rest of the code in that if block. This happens because ajax requests aren't instant, once the request is sent out, the program continues with whatever is next. If you need the code below the ajax request the run only after there has been a response then you need to put that code inside the "success" function.

Comment: Let's not forget about setting `async` option to `false`

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose, that would mean no other functions could properly execute while that function is being run. That might be inconvenient for a user. It would be much better to move the code to the success function

Comment: And yet that's exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: But using async:false results in a loss of functionality, he should only use that if it's absolutely necessary, whereas for this question there is another way around without that loss in functionality.